# write() returns error:invalid argument when using serial port

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am trying to send data using the serial port but the write command always returns -1.

This is the code for the write command.

```
int WriteComm( int Comid, void *buf, int nobtw )
{
unsigned long nobw;
nobw = write(Comid, buf, nobtw);

move(10,5);
perror("");
sleep(10);

return nobw;
}
```

and this is the code that calls it

```
gnobw = WriteComm(theApp.idComDev[Seg],&head[1],1); //send network address
```

I am getting invalid argument as the error but after looking on google I cant find anything explaning what this means or how to fix it. the closes thing I found was [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tar-devst0-cannot-write-invalid-argument/)  but it uses st0 not ttyS0 so im not sure if its even the same thing.

can anyone explain what i am doing wrong to get this error and how to fix it ?

Comment: Your `perror()` call is after a call to some routine called `move()` -- how do you know the error is even connected to the `write()` call?

Comment: Did you even  bother to look at the write( ) man page? You can google all you want, but the answer is somewhere in man write.

Comment: @Ernest -- yes, he doesn't know for sure, but (as a point of information) errno does not change unless his call to move( ) calls some other system-level function.

Comment: @Pete the man page does not have the invalid argument error in its error list.

Comment: @Ernest i have tried it without the move call and it the same and the move call does not fail so it would not set errno.

Comment: @Skeith - the normal man page for write (http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) has this definition for EINVAL: fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for writing; or the file was opened with the O_DIRECT flag, and either the address specified in buf, the value specified in count, or the current file offset is not suitably aligned.

Comment: @Adrian this is the code to open the port so i dont see how either of the situations it states are applicable    idComDev[i] = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

Comment: @Skeith -- wtf are you talking about? Do a man 2 write as Adrian Cox and I want you to do and you'll see your error: EINVAL. It has nothing to do with how you opened the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should only be examining `errno` (this includes calling `perror()`) if the `write` call failed, which it indicates by returning -1.  If the write succeeds, it leaves `errno` unchanged.

In order to test for this you should really be assigning the return value to a variable with a signed type - preferably `ssize_t` - not an `unsigned long`.

Comment: the perror code is only there for debugging and would not be in production code as it is checked elsewhere when the writecom function is called als you have still not provided an answer to the question that was asked

Comment: @Skeith: If the `write` call succeeds it will *leave `errno` unchanged*.  This means that the `EINVAL` you are seeing might not be from the `write` call at all.  If it *is* from the `write()` call, then you are passing it a bad file descriptor number - perhaps `Seg` isn't what you think it is, or perhaps that array has been overwritten by a stray write elsewhere.  Set a breakpoint in `WriteComm` and print the value of `Comid`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting EINVAL back from write( ). That means one of  your arguments to the function is invalid: EINVAL = **E**rror, **INVAL**id argument. There are three arguments to the function:

```
     arg               your variable
---------------------- -------------
int file descriptor:     Comid
void *buf:               buf   
size_t size:             nobtw
```

write( ) puked when it saw one of those three. So one of those three is wrong.

So put a printf( ) before the call to write( ) and see which one (or two; or three) is wrong.

Where is the actual code (not your memory of the code) that does the open( )? Is the file descriptor returned by open( ) the same one (Comid) you are trying to write( ) onto? If not, there's your problem.

That is the likely error in this mashup.

Comment: EINVAL would be typically for the fd. An invalid buffer address would return EFAULT, and the length is usually unchecked.

Comment: @ninjalj It depends on device which you are working with. I just spent a few hours trying to figure out why diagnostic port of my phone gives me EINVAL though the file descriptor is correct. It turned out, device validated each command and reported error as EINVAL. In my case I had in buf a command with  wrong header.

Comment: @Alex: that API is not idiomatic. Typically, sending commands would be done either via ioctl(), or if done via write(), the response and errors would come back via read(). Validating buf as a write()-level error could be thought of as a violation of layering.

Comment: @ninjalj I think you are right in most cases, but If I had got one of those I probably would never come on this SO page :) Even after I had read Pete Wilson's answer I spent a lot of time trying to find problems in pointer to buf or its type, but problem was in data. I just want to help those who will come here in similar unusual situation :) I was working with qualcomm's /dev/diag on Android.

Answer (score 0):

EINVAL from write(3) means:
The STREAM or multiplexer referenced by fildes is linked (directly or indirectly) downstream from a multiplexer.

What this basically means is that something else has your serial port open for writing at the same time -- at least intermittently. USB to serial converters seem to be particularly vulnerable to this. Other serial drivers will generally only allow you to open them once.

Source:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/write